# Why do my Android Studio directories and files look different for me than my coworkers?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

So, I have been working on AS for an applications' class I have, and when I create a project it looks like this:

[My files and directories and  in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCLBg.jpg)

I like this GUI, I have grown into it. But for some reason, my classmates have a different one, with the files put into folders put into folders put into folders like this one:

[My coworkers' files and directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEhry.jpg)

Why does it look different to me? The apps do not seem to work either when I open them in my AS. Is there something I need to download or is this an update?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had this problem, look for the system settings and look for the button "Check for Updates" in the "Updates" section. You need to update the whole Android Studio version.